# Python - Can't match strings from file

Tags: numpy

I have this `textfile.txt`:

```
i
car
air
me
```

And a dictionary is defined as:

```
dictionary = {"me":3, "you":4, "else": 10, "i":2}
```

I'm looking for a way to delete the words in textfile.txt from the dictionary in a generalizable way (I'm using a loop here) My attempt:

```
words_to_delete = open("textfile.txt", "r")
for i in words_to_delete.readlines():
    del dictionary[i]

# Output: KeyError: 'i\n'
```

Going further, I think is because of this:

```
for i in words_to_delete.readlines():
    print(i == "me")

# Output: False, False, False, False
```

Why the values from the loop are not comparable from the `textfile.txt`?

If I run this:

```
for i in words_to_delete.readlines():
    print(type(i))

<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

It's a string, so why the strings `i` and `me` from the dictionary returns `False` when comparing it with brute-force written strings?

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the whitespaces (or in this case `\n` which is a newline. Call the strip method on the strings that have `\n` at the end. (like s.strip())

Comment: I don't understand. The text file doesn't have any whitespaces.

Comment: When you read the lines the newlines at the end stay. Newlines are whitespaces like tab and space

Comment: Do you see the `\n` in your keyerror? `"i\n"` and `"i"` are obviously different